# Minimized Windows

Tags: settings

How do I find (or have them displayed at the top or bottom of the screen) windows that I have minimized? My daughter did something to my computer and when I minimize a window it disappears.

Comment: Can you tell us what specific distro you are using?  Is it Ubuntu, or one of its variants?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, you can click on the program icon and it will bring up the windows of that program that are open, or, you can press ALT+TAB and switch to the window you want